# Prompt user to Time In/Time Out once a day?

Tags: c#, ms-access, insert

I am developing an Attendance Management System, I want it to prompt the user to time in/out once per day. What I'm thinking is it will select the employeeID and Indate,intime and out time from the Database and if indate and intime has value it will show time in once per day obly samethig thig w/ timeout select indate,outtime etc. Here's my code

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //VALIDATION
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = @"    SELECT EmployeeID, Firstname, Lastname
                                        FROM tblEmployee 
                                        WHERE EmployeeID = @1";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", textBox1.Text);
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {

                    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = reader[0].ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = reader[1].ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = reader[2].ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();
                    savetimein();


            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Employee ID");
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    //SAVE TO DATABASE
    private void savetimein()
    {

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [TimeinTimeout](EmployeeID, Firstname, Lastname, InDate, InTime) VALUES (@1,@2,@3,@4,@5)";
        command.Parameters.Clear();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", textBox1.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@4", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@5", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved!");
        this.Hide();
        Form1 Mm = new Form1();
        Mm.ShowDialog();

    }
```

Comment: Where are you querying when the last time they signed in is?  You seem to know what you have to do - what's your question?

Comment: I'm thinking about limiting the user's log in but I would want to know is what is the code to setermine if a certain column has value something like that

Comment: If database column has no value it will excecute but if it has value it will not

Answer (score 0):

You should check your table for the last login date of the user.  **I'm going to assume that your `InDate` and `InTime` columns are `DATE` and `TIME` columns, respectively - or at least if they're not, that you're storing dates and times in a sensible, sortable manner (e.g. YYYY-MM-DD and using 24 hour clock for time) - if not, you'll need to work out how you're going to sort**.  Your SQL query would look something like this (if you want to check the last 24 hours):

```
SELECT InDate, InTime 
FROM [TimeinTimeout] 
WHERE EmployeeID = @p1 
ORDER BY InDate DESC, InTime DESC
```

You would then use a `OleDbDataReader` to read the results from that (if any - if none then you know they haven't logged in ever), check for nulls (if those columns are nullable), and check that the `InDate` and `InTime` are less than 24 hours ago, etc.

If you want to just check that they logged in **today**, it's a little simpler:

```
SELECT InDate 
FROM [TimeinTimeout] 
WHERE EmployeeID = @p1 
ORDER BY InDate DESC
```

And you could use `ExecuteScalar()`, check for null, and if not null then check that the date is today's date.

Also keep in mind that you need to check not just for `null` in C#, but also check that your return value(s) are not `== DBNull.Value` (which is not the same as `null` in C#).

Comment: I've thought of something else actually, SELECT EmployeeID,InDate,InTime FROM TimeinTimeout WHERE EmployeeID = @1; if(reader[3] == null) { //save to database } else { MessageBox.Show("Time in once per day"); would this work? Im just a novice C# programmer

Comment: You need the `ORDER BY` in there to guarantee that you're getting the latest data - if the user has multiple rows in that table you might always end up returning the earliest one, or some other one than the latest...